# Differences between up and back (in programming)

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know what is the differences between the `back` and `up` actions.

I've already found online how they work, but I didn't find what different happens when I trigger them.

When I intent another activity and go back with `up` action, it seems to just show again my last activity without executing any method (my images show like it was cached).

When I intent another activity and go back with `back` action, it seems to reconstruct the entire layout (my images reloads).

What really happens?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `up` action?

Comment: When you press the `up` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must understand the concept of Up and Back navigation, you should read this link [about Navigation with UP and Back](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

When pressed back button the actual screen is removed but when pressed up button relaunch the parent-activity.

In your manifest need to add propert ***launchMode*** of activity, something like this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.client.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I hope you serve.